# How to get all ENS domains for one wallet address with web3.py

Tags: python, web3py

I am trying to write a code in python that returns the ENS domain of a given wallet address with [web3.py](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ens_overview.html), but I am having problems when the wallet has registered more than one ENS and I can't find anything in the documentation about this issue.

Here is an example code:

```
infura_endpoint = f'https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/{infura_api_key}'

w3 = Web3(HTTPProvider(infura_endpoint))
print(w3.isConnected())  # This returns True
ns = ns.fromWeb3(web3=w3)

domain = ns.name('0xC99c2bdA0BEaA0B4c9774B48B81307C00e19CAde')
print(domain)  # This prints None

# This try/except block prints "Something went wrong" because the domain variable is None
try:
    assert ns.address(domain) == '0xC99c2bdA0BEaA0B4c9774B48B81307C00e19CAde'
except AssertionError:
    print('Something went wrong')

print(ns.address('seeds.eth'))  # "seeds.eth" is one of the domains that should be returned
```

I would appreciate any help you can give me.

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked for me (via Alchemy to connect to web3) and leveraging the ENS package.

```
from ens import ENS
from web3 import Web3

ALCHEMY_KEY = "<YOUR_KEY>"

alchemy_url = f"https://eth-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/{ALCHEMY_KEY}"
w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(alchemy_url))
ns = ENS.fromWeb3(w3)

addr = "0xD2Af803ad747ea12Acf5Ae468056703aE48785b5"
wallet_name = ns.name(addr)

print(wallet_name)
```

The address used should resolve to `whaleshark.eth`